# Work with Binding inside an external function in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, binding

I'm currently learning SwiftUI and want to develop my own app. I have designed a `LoginView` and a `LoginHandler` that should take care of all the logic behind a login. When the user enters the wrong username/password, an Alert should appear on the screen. I solved this with the state variable `loginError`. But now comes the tricky part, as i want to pass a binding of this variable to my login function in the `LoginHandler`. Take a look at the following code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct LoginView: View
{
    @EnvironmentObject var loginHandler: LoginHandler
    
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    @State private var loginError: Bool = false
    
    ...
    
    private func login()
    {
        loginHandler.login(username: username, password: password, error: $loginError)
    }
}
```

I am now trying to change the value of error inside my login function:

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class LoginHandler: ObservableObject
{
    public func login(username: String, password: String, error: Binding<Bool>)
    {
        error = true
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the error

> Cannot assign to value: 'error' is a 'let' constant

which makes sense I think because you can't edit the parameters in swift. I have also tried `_error = true` because I once saw the underscore in combination with a binding, but this doesn't worked either.

But then I came up with a working solution: `error.wrappedValue = true`. My only problem with that is the following statement from Apples Developer Documentation:

> This property provides primary access to the value’s data. However, you don’t access wrappedValue directly. Instead, you use the property variable created with the @Binding attribute.

Although I'm super happy that it works, I wonder if there is any better way to solve this situation?

#### Update 20.3.21: New edge case

In the comment section I mentioned a case where you don't know how many times your function will be used. I will now provide a little code example:

Imagine a list of downloadable files (`DownloadView`) that you will get from your backend:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct DownloadView: View
{
    @EnvironmentObject var downloadHandler: DownloadHandler
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            ForEach(downloadHandler.getAllDownloadableFiles())
            {
                file in DownloadItemView(file: file)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Every downloadable file has a name, a small description and its own download button:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct DownloadItemView: View
{
    @EnvironmentObject var downloadHandler: DownloadHandler
    
    @State private var downloadProgress: Double = -1
    
    var file: File
    
    var body: some View
    {
        HStack
        {
            VStack
            {
                Text(file.name)
                Text(file.description)
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            if downloadProgress < 0
            {
                // User can start Download
                Button(action: {
                    downloadFile()
                })
                {
                    Text("Download")
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // User sees download progress
                ProgressView(value: $downloadProgress)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func downloadFile()
    {
        downloadHandler.downloadFile(file: file, progress: $downloadProgress)
    }
}
```

And now finally the 'DownloadHandler':

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class DownloadHandler: ObservableObject
{
    public func downloadFile(file: File, progress: Binding<Double>)
    {
        // Example for changing the value
        progress = 0.5
    }
}
```

Comment: Your own solution is exactly what I would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you're trying to do, but it will cause problems later on down the line because you're dealing with State here. Now one solution would be:

- You could just abstract the `error` to the class, but then you would have the `username` and `password` in one spot and the error in another.

The ideal solution then is to abstract it all away in the same spot. Take away all of the properties from your view and have it like this:

```
   import SwiftUI

struct LoginView: View
{
    @EnvironmentObject var loginHandler: LoginHandler
    

   
   // login() <-- Call this when needed
    ...
    
    
}
```

Then in your class:

```
    import Foundation
    import SwiftUI
    
  @Published error: Bool = false
   var username = ""
   var password = ""

    class LoginHandler: ObservableObject
    {
        
       

       public func login()    {
           //If you can't login then throw your error here
           self.error = true
   }
    }
```

The only left for you to do is to update the `username` and password` and you can do that with this for example

```
TextField("username", text: $loginHandler.username)
TextField("username", text: $loginHandler.password)
```

Edit: Adding an update for the edge case:

```
  import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: gridModel) {
        
            ForEach(0..<20) { x in
                CustomView(id: x)
            }
        }
    }
    let gridModel = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 100, maximum: 100), spacing: 10),
                     GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 100, maximum: 100), spacing: 10),
                     GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 100, maximum: 100), spacing: 10)
    ]
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct CustomView: View {
    @State private var downloaded = false
    @State private var progress = 0
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = StateManager()
    let id: Int
    

    
    var body: some View {
        showAppropriateView()
    }
    @ViewBuilder private func showAppropriateView() -> some View {
        if viewModel.downloadStates[id] == true {
            VStack {
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.blue)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                
                
            }
        } else {
            Button("Download") {
                downloaded = true
                viewModel.saveState(of: id, downloaded)
            }
        }
    }
}

final class StateManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var downloadStates: [Int : Bool] = [:] {
        didSet { print(downloadStates)}
    }
    
    func saveState(of id: Int,_ downloaded: Bool) {
        downloadStates[id] = downloaded
    }
}
```

I didn't add the progress to it because I'm short on time but I think this conveys the idea. You can always abstract away the individual identity needed by other views.

Either way, let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: Okay, this seems to work in my situation. But this wouldn't work if would call the function from multiple sources that you don't know before runtime, eg. if you're handling multiple file downloads and want to show the progress for every file.

Comment: I would like to see an example, this base model can be adjusted to fit that use case I think

Comment: I'm quite new here, were should I provide you the example? I think the comment section isn't the best place for that...

Comment: Yes, just Edit your original question and add your comment there, just preface your edit with something like: To describe an edge case

Comment: Just added that one, feel free to take a look.

Comment: @KingKevin23 I just added an edit to my post. You can copy and paste it to get the idea. Let me know if that helps

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and sharing this code. I really like the idea, but at that point it would probably be easier to just use `.wrappedValue` as its shorter and easier to understand..

Answer (score 4):

You can update parameters of a function as well, here is an example, this not using Binding or State, it is inout!

> I am now trying to change the value of error inside my login function:

> Cannot assign to value: 'error' is a 'let' constant

So with this method or example you can!

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var value: String = "Hello World!"
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(value)
            .padding()
        
        Button("update") {
            
            testFuction(value: &value)
        }
        
    }
}


func testFuction(value: inout String) {
    
    value += " updated!"
}
```

Comment: Oh, didn't thought about that on. But what if I want to change 'value' inside an escaping closure?

Comment: if you read **inout** like this: in->out it make more meaning, comes inside gets outside, so it is kind of closure

Comment: yeah, but when you use it inside an escaping closure you're getting "Escaping closure captures 'inout' parameter 'value'"

Comment: basically I wanted inform you about **inout**, now you want solve spacial issue or question, which is better asked in a new question, then we can work there and share code as well, we cannot solve multi issue in one question. If you like make a question and I come to that one to help.